# Along and Alongside

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

Look at these sentences:

**I walk along the road**

**The traffic jam along the road**

**I walk alongside the road**

**The traffic jam alongside the road**

The first sentence means as the same direction as the road (correct me If I'm wrong), Though, I don't know if the second means "the traffic is in a line next to the road" or if the traffic is on top of the road.

And when should I use along and alongside ? (Can you guys please give me examples and tell me all the meanings of each word?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first two cases **along** means **from one end to the other**. Direction is not relevant to the use of along in this case.
**Along** has three meanings but **Alongside** has only one; next to, or together with

**Along or alongside** can be used when the meaning is **next to**.

However only **Along** can be used if the meaning is "**From one end to another**" or **"At a particular place"**

Examples

> We walked along the beach collecting small crabs in a bucket.
>
> Cars were parked all along the road.
>
> Somewhere along this road there's a garage.
>   [Link to C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/along)
>
> The new pill will be used alongside existing medicines..
>   [Link to C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alongside)

The new pill will be used along with existing medicines.

Comment: In the 2nd example, does it mean "they are next to the road, parked next to each other" or "they are parked close to each other on the road"?

Comment: @Thinking Boi; You can click the link and it will be explained to you.

Comment: Answers where you have to click a link to fully understand them are discouraged. Explanations should be incorporated into your answer.